# Wsgen class not found

Tags: java, web-services, spring, wsgen

I have little problem with wsgen, everytime when I use it, I get error "class not found".
I want use it for class StudentServiceEndpoint in directory webservices. Any ideas how should I do it?

Here is picture of my direcory structure:
http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/4274/5g8.png

http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/737/eo4.png

PS. sorry for my english ;p

**EDIT:** I edited the image.

Comment: Use `tree /a /f` for show the names of your classes.

Comment: Ok, now is image with classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to target/classes in terminal and run

```
wsgen -verbose -keep -cp . pl.edu.pk.webservices.StudentServiceEndpoint
```

Summary of used flags:

`-verbose` - show additional information

`-keep` - don't remove generated stuff

`-cp .` -classpatch is in current location

Comment: Spent near 2hours to understand this :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to the bin\classes\target directory in command promt

and run wsgen -verbose -keep -cp . v.com.Impl class name.

Comment: In my case into Workspace/Project/build/classes directory in cmd